# Override mails directory in prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, email, module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am programming new module, i want to send mail automatically to employee after creating his account. i override AdminEmployeesController controller but when i call Mail::Send(), this last use mails directory in the root of prestashop project not that i created in my module root.

```
class AdminEmployeesController extends AdminEmployeesControllerCore
{
    /**
     * Object creation
     */
    public function processAdd()
    {
        if(parent::processAdd()){
            $this->sendMail();
        }

    }

    /*
    * Send email to the new employer
    * */
    public function sendMail()
    {

        Mail::Send(
            $this->context->language->id,
            'selcreate_account',
            Mail::l('Creation de compte'),
            array(
                '{firstname}' =>Psql(Tools::getValue('firstname')),
                '{lastname}' =>Psql(Tools::getValue('lastname')),
                '{passwd}' => Psql(Tools::getValue('passwd')),
                '{email}' => Psql(Tools::getValue('email')),
                '{shopname}' => 'shop 1',),
            Psql(Tools::getValue('email')),
            Psql(Tools::getValue('firstname')).' '.Psql(Tools::getValue('lastname')),
            $this->context->shop->name
        );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide your template path.

Here is Mail function parameters:

```
/**
 * Send Email
 *
 * @param int $id_lang Language of the email (to translate the template)
 * @param string $template Template: the name of template not be a var but a string !
 * @param string $subject
 * @param string $template_vars
 * @param string $to
 * @param string $to_name
 * @param string $from
 * @param string $from_name
 * @param array $file_attachment Array with three parameters (content, mime and name). You can use an array of array to attach multiple files
 * @param bool $modeSMTP
 * @param string $template_path
 * @param bool $die
 * @param string $bcc Bcc recipient
 */
public static function Send($id_lang, $template, $subject, $template_vars, $to,
    $to_name = null, $from = null, $from_name = null, $file_attachment = null, $mode_smtp = null,
    $template_path = _PS_MAIL_DIR_, $die = false, $id_shop = null, $bcc = null, $reply_to = null)
{
```

And here is your function (assuming your templates are in the `mails` directory of your module):

```
/*
* Send email to the new employer
* */
public function sendMail()
{

    Mail::Send(
        $this->context->language->id,
        'selcreate_account',
        Mail::l('Creation de compte'),
        array(
            '{firstname}' =>Psql(Tools::getValue('firstname')),
            '{lastname}' =>Psql(Tools::getValue('lastname')),
            '{passwd}' => Psql(Tools::getValue('passwd')),
            '{email}' => Psql(Tools::getValue('email')),
            '{shopname}' => 'shop 1',),
        Psql(Tools::getValue('email')),
        Psql(Tools::getValue('firstname')).' '.Psql(Tools::getValue('lastname')),
        $this->context->shop->name,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        _PS_MODULE_DIR_.'your_module/mails/'
    );
}
```

Comment: Using this function i get this issue :  Error- The following template email does not exist : C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\override\controllers\admin/mails/fr/selcreate_account.txt

Comment: You need to provide the right path to your module in place of `dirname(__FILE__).'/mails/'`i'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should define your directory path `$template_path` in `send()` like

If you are creating module then your path should be

```
_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'yourmodulename/mails/'
```

Hope it helps..